# How can I test the divergence of a recursive sequence formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The recursive formula is the following:

$a_n = \left(\dfrac{2n^4 - 1}{1 + 3n^4}\right) a_{n+1}$   ;      $a_1 = 1 $

In which fundamentals need I to base me for solving this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following loose-ish bound: for all $n\geq 1$,
$$
\frac{3n^4+1}{2n^4-2} \geq \frac{3}{2}
$$
so $a_{n+1} \geq \frac{3}{2}a_n$ for all $n\geq 1$.

**More** (place your mouse over the gray area to reveal its contents):

> By induction, show that $$a_n\geq \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1}.$$

Comment: All too easy.  ;-)) +1

Comment: @Dr.MV "I like my math problems like I like my eggs."

Comment: As long as the answers aren't "poached."  Yes I just wrote that!  ;-)   And I hope that cracked you up.  Ouch.